# Shopware 6: How long do articles that have been placed on the wish list by customers remain stored?

Tags: shopware6

How long do articles that have been placed on the wish list by customers remain stored?

I expect a short answer for my customer. How long the wish list is stored or even how long it is in the cache

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wishlist items are stored indefinitely in a dedicated database table for all logged-in customers. There is no clean up for this.

For guest customers, it's a bit more complex. If they've disabled cookies, they can't use the wishlist at all without logging in.

Otherwise, it uses the browser's local storage, falling back to session storage and failing that uses a cookie storage.
Local storage has no inherent expiration, but can be cleared by the user or browser. Session storage is cleared after the session ends - usually when closing the last tab of the page.

So for a short answer: Usually, the wishlist does not expire.